# visual studio 2008 editor cant able to enter text?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

Am using the visual studio 2008 editor for create c# programs.In my editor I can enter only upto 160 columns.If i Enter the 161 column i cant able to enter that column.It automatically goes next line First column.How to Solve this Problem in my Visual studio editor?

```
for Example it show like this,

<%--   <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="50px" style="border -bottom:1px solid #E5E5E5; border-top:1px solid #E5E5E5;">   .
```

The First line Start with 79th column and (-bottom starts in next line first column).and my vertical scroll bar does not show...

Answer (score 1):

Try Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> 'All Languages' or the specific language you're using.

Disable Word Wrap.